# MySQL Trigger - Using logical inserted table to insert into another table

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, phpmyadmin

I am currently in the process of writing my first trigger in MySQL within PHPmyadmin. I would like it so that when an item in one table is updated, a row in another table is inserted. Several columns of the row that is to be inserted in the second table are determined by the values being updated in the first table.

Therefore, I need to INSERT a new row in table B when an update occurs on table A. And some of the values of the columns in table B are to be defined by the values in the updated table A row which caused the trigger to run.

Please find the trigger below.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `before_categoryiteminstance_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `TABLEA`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
declare f_guidcategoryiteminstance int; 
declare f_guidcategory int; 
INSERT INTO TABLEB
SET
f_guidcategoryiteminstance =(SELECT guidcategoryiteminstance FROM inserted),
f_guidcategory =(SELECT guidcategory FROM inserted),
guiduser= f_guidcategory,
guidcategoryinstance= f_guidcategoryiteminstance,
number= number +1,
dateofaction= NOW(); END
```

The trigger can be added to the DB fine. However, when I attempt to update a row on table A (which should cause the trigger to run), I get an error stating that the table Inserted does not exist. However, I was under the impression that Inserted should be a logical table that contains the results of the initial part of the trigger. Is this only the case if the trigger is being run on an insert and not an update? If so, is there an equivalent for an update trigger?

Comment: @Matthew- Did you get the answer to your question...?? Are your implementing it on Windows or Linux..??